# Constraints en un chatView

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, constraints, uicollectionview

tengo un menu con tres opciones, la ultima opción es un chat muy sencillo, al entrar por primera vez, se acomodan bien los globos de dialogo, pero al seleccionar otra opción del menu y después regresar al chat, los globos se alinean, checken las fotos para que pueda ser mas claro.

al entrar por primera vez al view: [image: constraints acomodados]

y después se desacomodan los constraints: [image: se desacomodan los constraints]

ya lo intente de los storyboards pero me sucede lo mismo, también intente un layoutifneeded, y lo mismo, no lo coloco en un viewWillApear por que lo creo en un UIView, no en un ViewController, también intenté desde el delegado "cellForItem" colocar un:

```
      cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

incluso en la celda customizada en la función:

```
       override func awakeFromNib() {
              super.awakeFromNib()
              self.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
```

y este es el código de los constrains..

```
        var dialogViewLeading: NSLayoutConstraint?
        var dialogViewTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint? 

         func setupConstraints() {
    dialogView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    commentTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    dialogView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    dialogView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    let commentUserLeading = dialogView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 50)
    let commentAnswerLeading = dialogView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 30)
    let commentUserTrailling = dialogView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -30)
    let commentAnswerTrailing = dialogView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -50)
    dialogViewLeading = comments?.isUser == false ? commentAnswerLeading : commentUserLeading
    dialogViewTrailing = comments?.isUser == false ? commentAnswerTrailing : commentUserTrailling
    dialogViewLeading?.isActive = true
    dialogViewTrailing?.isActive = true

    commentTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dialogView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    commentTextView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dialogView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    commentTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dialogView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    commentTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dialogView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2).isActive = true
}
```

le paso la función para los constraints al setear los datos al modelo...

```
       var comments: CommentsModel? {
    didSet {
        guard let comment = comments else { return }
        commentTextView.text = comment.description

        let colorCommentUser = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2224622369, green: 0.7220397592, blue: 0.8129917979, alpha: 1)
        let colorCommentAnswer = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9175571799, green: 0.9176927209, blue: 0.9175387025, alpha: 1)
        dialogView.backgroundColor = comment.isUser == false ? colorCommentAnswer : colorCommentUser
        commentTextView.textColor = comment.isUser == false ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.3332946301, green: 0.3333562315, blue: 0.333286047, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.9175571799, green: 0.9176927209, blue: 0.9175387025, alpha: 1)
        setupConstraints()
    }
}
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que esta pasando? o que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on algo de ayuda de Angel Teyez, lo que hice fue colocar un delegado del CollectionView, didEndDisplaying y simplemente recargar la función de la activación de los constraints:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CommentsGetCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? CommentsGetCollectionViewCell else { return }
         cell.ActivateConstraintsForComments()
}
```

como en cellForItem creo la celda y le digo cual clase es... y simplemente llamo la función.

Answer (score 0):

Creo el problema es que necesitas desactivar los *constraints* anteriores antes de activar los nuevos. Al parecer tienes un `UICollectionView` y supongo estás reusando las celdas en `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, esto podría estar causando que ambos *constraints* (*leading* y *trailing*) se estén activando y por eso se alineen.

Podrías probar dentro de `setupConstraints()` algo como:

```
func setupConstraints() {
    ...
    let commentUserLeading = ...
    let commentAnswerLeading = ...
    let commentUserTrailling = ...
    let commentAnswerTrailing = ...
    if comments?.isUser == true {
        commentAnswerLeading.isActive = false
        commentAnswerTrailing.isActive = false
        commentUserLeading.isActive = true
        commentUserTrailing.isActive = true
    } else {
        commentUserLeading.isActive = false
        commentUserTrailing.isActive = false
        commentAnswerLeading.isActive = true
        commentAnswerTrailing.isActive = true
    }

    /* O incluso más resumido podría ser...
    commentUserLeading.isActive = comments?.isUser == true
    commentUserTrailing.isActive = comments?.isUser == true
    commentAnswerLeading.isActive = comments?.isUser == true
    commentAnswerTrailing.isActive = comments?.isUser == true
    */

    ...
}
```

Comment: la validación hacerla después de activar los constraints? voy a intentarlo y aviso que tal

Comment: Después de declarar las variables con los contraints, validar si `isUser` y activar todos los constraints de _User_ y desactivar todos los de _Answer_. (Actualicé la respuesta porque estoy viendo que activé sólo un par de constraints y así no funcionará, lo siento n_n' )

Comment: lo intente de la siguiente manera, que según yo es lo mismo pero con cada uno de los constraints...: commentUserLeading.isActive = comments?.isUser == false ? false : true

Comment: siguen sin funcionar, creo que tienes razón por lo que mencionas de reutilizar las celdas, en cellForItem, de alguna manera se podría llamar una función como un willappear en el UIView? tal vez recargando las celdas en una función así no tendría problemas, como un didappear... solo es una idea

Comment: Dentro de `UICollectionViewDelegate` hay métodos parecidos a `willAppear` y `didDisappear` para las celdas: `willDisplay` y `didEndDisplaying`, respectivamente. Pero no creo que activando/desactivando los constraints dentro de éstos sea la mejor solución. Podrías tratar de declarar los _commentConstraints_ como variables de la clase y crear un método público llamado `updateCommentConstraints` (o algo así), llamarlo dentro del `cellForItem` y que éste sólo se encargue de desactivar y activar esos Constraints. Y elimina de `setupConstraints()` las activaciones para que no lleguen a causar bugs.

Comment: pues intente lo que mencionas, pero nada, y pues utilice el didEndDisplay, y actualiza correctamente los constrainst sin problema, si encuentro otra manera les aviso